# Generating a unique student number with a check digit using vb.Net

Tags: vb.net

I am writing a program that needs to generate a student number with eight digits, the 8th (last) digit being the check digit and is calculated by summing-up the first seven digits, divide the result by 10 and take the remainder and subtract it from 10. There is no input from the user. When a button is clicked the code has to execute and display the student number in a msgBox. The student number has to be incremented by 1 every time a student registers.
Please help...

Comment: What results are you expecting? Also as there is no relation to previously created numbers, the outcome will be the same each time. You message box won't show the number either as your not using the variable `StudentNumber`.

Comment: I'm really stumped by the thought process that produces this line of code and matching comment: `Dim Sum As Integer = 0 'increment student number by 1`

Comment: @XN16- From the numbers in my code, am looking for something like: student number before check digit=1200001 and after the check digit has been calculated, should be 12000017 (check digit=7). For the other line of comment, am not sure if I get you, am new to vb and I want to learn as much as I can.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever- That's a mistake because I've been writing and editing this code for more than I don't know. I guess that comment should be by the i variable..

Comment: @SATSON- When the first student registers, the student number would be 1200001_ (_ is for the check digit which would have to be calculated), then get the sum of 1200001 (1+2+0+0+0+0+1), then divide it by 10, then subtract the remainder from 10...that should give the check(8th) digit.

Comment: What the hell! `Sum = Sum + (1 + 2 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 0) + i`

Comment: @equisde- funny...hahaha!

Answer (score 0):

Try Like this

```
 Public Number As Integer = 1200000 'first seven digits of student number

  Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object,
  ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

        Dim i As Integer = Number
        Dim StudentNumber As Integer
        i += 1

        While (i > 0)

            StudentNumber += (i Mod 10)
            i /= 10

        End While

        StudentNumber = 10 - (StudentNumber Mod 10)

        StudentNumber = CInt(Number.ToString & StudentNumber.ToString)

        Number +=1

        MsgBox("Your student number is "" StudentNumber" & StudentNumber)

    End Sub
```

Comment: @SATSON- Thanks, but still something is missing. Before anyone registers, the number is 1200000. But as more students registers the number would change, as in the 1st student would be number 1200001, the 2nd would be number 1200002,...etc. So, the student number for the 1st student would be something like: 1200001+the check digit.

Comment: yes. you asking this correct. something missing means want? want kind of changes you need

Comment: @SATSON- I need the seventh digit of the number to be incremented by 1 every time a student registers. Once the seventh digit has been incremented, then the check (8th) digit can be calculated.

Comment: always register no is 1200000. or what is difference between `1200000+1, 0+1 (1200000)`

Comment: @SATSON- The difference is, 120000+1=1200001 is what I need to be displayed in the msgbox together with check digit...forget about the 0+1 (1200000), I don't need that.